# Cordova 3.6.3 downloading file in Android

Tags: android, file, cordova

I m using Cordova 3.6.3 and I want to download file in Android. I added all permission about file and file transfer and also add file and file transfer  plugin. its give me Error code:1 .its create file on memory but its only name .its empty .Where is the problem?

I lookup other solution but its not working.

```
  var resimURL= "https://farm"+url.farm+".staticflickr.com/"+url.server+"/"+url.id+"_"+url.secret+"_b.jpg";
  //alert("Download");
  alert(resimURL);

  var remoteFile =resimURL;
  var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
      function(fileSystem) {
          fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
          function(fileEntry) {
              var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
              alert(localPath);
              if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                  localPath =fileSystem.root.toUrl()+localPath.substring(7);
                  alert(localPath);
              }
              var ft = new FileTransfer();
              ft.download(remoteFile, localPath,
                  function(entry) {
                      alert("Download Complete");
                  },
              fail);
          },
      fail);
      },
  fail);
  function fail(error) {
      alert("error"+error.code);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it ,its now working ..

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.download(remoteFile,
            "/sdcard/Pictures/"+url.id+"_"+url.secret+"_b.jpg",
            function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            }, fail);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encode your uri before you pass it to download method:

`var resimURL = encodeURI("your uri");`

This is described in the documentation as follow:

> source: URL of the server to download the file, as encoded by encodeURI().

Hope this helps.

reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: @NazırDogan hmm..error code 1 is FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR. Does your download uri properly download a file when you try on browser?

Comment: yes .its downloading .for example this link in my app https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3950/14951861574_27472abe70_b.jpg

Comment: @NazırDogan is error code 1 from download method? I am just wondering if it is from the right method since you are using the same failure function for all methods. Also, there is an optional parameter for download method called trustAllHost. Setting it to true will accept all security certificates: download(source,target, SC, FC, trustAllHosts)

Comment: Also, just in case, could you post the permission part too?

Comment: Hi SLee , I changed something .its working now .I answered the question and I added before all permission for file transfer.anyway now its working thank you :)